# SQL Order by lexicographical order, but with longer string first

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

In SQL Server, I have a table with a column I want to sort. If I apply the usual `ORDER BY`, it does the following, as expected:

```
banana
bananaphone
car
carpet
dishes
//etc
```

However, I would like to have them sorted this other way:

```
bananaphone
banana
carpet
car
dishes
//etc
```

Still lexicographically, but if the letters match and one is longer than the other, place the longer one first.

Is it possible to do such a query in a T-SQL?

I don't even know if this sorting algorithm has a name, I couldn't find it.

Please note that the data in this post is just an example, and I will be storing user-defined data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
declare @YourTable table (YourColumn varchar(100));
insert into @YourTable

select 'bananaphone' union all
select 'banana' union all
select 'carpet' union all
select 'car' union all
select 'dishes' union all
select 'carpet' union all
select 'cars' union all
select 'CARP'

select  YourColumn
from    @YourTable
order
by      YourColumn+replicate(char(255), 100-len(YourColumn));
```

Comment: @NathanSkerl that's a great technique, but if the characters in the word are after 'x' (ie, y&z) it won't get sorted properly. I suggest using the highest ASCII char like this `order by s+replicate(CHAR(255), 100-len(s))`

Comment: @John, yes, taking that into consideration, this solution works for me

Comment: @John yes, good point. The length of 50 might also be limiting.